No internet connection with ethernet and rndis at the same time
So i have a Raspberry Pi4 with Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS installed on it. For communications with several different systems i had to disable the network manager and configure the network myself.
For that i had to create two RNDIS connections named usb0 and usb1. usb0 is connected to a sim modem which provides a mobile internet connection and usb1 is connected to a different pc.
Now i want to be able to connect to the Pi via ssh and the available ethernet port on the Pi but for some reason my internet connection via the usb0 interface stops working the second i start the eth0 interface.
The (shrank down) output of ifconfig:
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.129  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.225.58  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.225.255

usb1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.90.2  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 192.168.255.255

And the output of route -n:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 usb1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.225.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb0

I saw that the default route was pointing to eth0 so i changed it with
sudo ip route change default via 192.168.225.1 dev usb0
Then i got the following route:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.225.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 usb1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.225.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 usb0

But if i try to ping a website or open one in a browser i get no response. Even if i put an -I usb0 into the ping command. The moment i disable the eth0 connection the internet works fine.
What can i do to prevent this?
Also if i let the eth0 interface auto configure at startup inside the /etc/network/interfaces.d file and have NO ethernet cable connected the bootup takes like 5 minutes instead of < 1 minute because i guess the eth0 is searching for an address which it does not get.
I hope somebody can help me with this.

removing gateway line for usb0 in sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces.d/usb0 file solved problem for me.
now it looks like
auto usb0
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0


What is 192.168.2.2 ? That address is inconsistent with the question. Addresses of the interfaces mentioned there are 192.168.1.129/24, 192.168.225.58/24 and 192.168.90.2/16 (did you really want to have /16 in the last one? It overlaps with the other two!). Did you mean "removing gateway in eth0", not usb0? As usb0 is your Internet connection, it should have a default gateway.

@raj you are right, the two address spaces are overlapping with the /16 netmask. Maybe that is causing some issues. But it should not interfere with requests to the "outside world" because i am pretty sure most sites do not have a 192.168.x.x address so it should default to the 192.168.225.1 gateway correct? But somehow there is still no connection

If your routing table is as you have shown in the question, it indeed should. Did you check with traceroute which way it is actually going and where the connection breaks?
